# How can additional tags be added for a term reference field while listing previously added vocabulary terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I am trying to modify a content type which has a term reference field to list all the terms in a vocabulary (like a select) while still allowing multiple tags and the addition of new tags.  It seems like it's something that should be pretty standard, however the Select list widget does not allow multiple tags, nor does it allow the addition of tags.  I have looked at about every module out there as far as I can tell and have been unable to find a solution.  The closest module to what I want is Autocomplete Deluxe, but it has so many bugs so as to render it virtually useless.  Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the Active Tags module?  There is a dev version out for D7 and I've had great success with it here in D6.  http://drupal.org/project/active_tags

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just tried it out. Active tags is nice, but I want it to display all of the tags to start off with, like a select with all of the terms in the vocabulary, while still allowing me to use multiple tags.

Comment: You might have to do it with two fields then.  The first being a tax field with a check box widget and then a second one where you can add additional tags.  Use the same tax vocab for both.  If all goes well in the world, after saving, any additional tags should automatically appear in the first field for later use across your site.

Comment: That's a really good idea.  I probably will have to end up doing that.  It just seems like there should be a way to do it with just one field, but maybe that's too much to hope for.  The module http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other would be perfect, except that it doesn't work for term reference fields.

Comment: I'd venture that with some CSS you could visually merge the two fields so that from a user perspective they'd look like one, eg, a field of checkboxes 3 or 4 per row (or however many look nice based upon the length of your tax terms) above a text input field for additional terms.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, too.  I think that's the best way of doing it.  Thanks so much for your help!